# How to generate a custom serialVersionUID in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

When I ask to Eclipse to create automatically a serialVersionUID, there are just two options, default (1L) or the generated one. I want to put in place something to generate a field like

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2018_07_13_1730L;
```

so that format is YYYY_MM_YY_HHmm'L'

Is it possible? Maybe via content assist, via a kind of macro or something like this...

Comment: I think it is possible to do it in Eclipse, but my concern is about if you understand the meaning of this constant and why you need such odd values for them.

Comment: Absolutely. Either that Id is a random number, or computed based on the fields of your class. Or manually stepped, starting with 0 or 1. I have seen many things since I started with Java 20+ years ago. But never such serial version uids.

Comment: Thank for your comment: yes we know how Serializable works and meaning of SVUID. Indeed, since we don't have a explicit versioning of represented entities, we use SVUID to vehicolate a meaning too: when object was coded first (or updated later).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via a template (but I'm not sure if this is a good idea here):

1. Open ***Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Templates***
2. Click ***New...***
3. Enter/choose the following:

   - Name: `serialVersionUID`
   - Context: *Java*
   - Description: `add serialVersionUID of current date`
   - Pattern: **`private static final long serialVersionUID = ${currentDate:date('yyyy_MM_dd_HHmm')}L;`**
4. Hit ***Ok*** and ***Apply and Close*** to apply the new template

If you type `ser` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, also the template should be suggested now.

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!